# Jhipster - use of isInAnyRole

Tags: jhipster

I have set up several roles in MySql, and I want to use the function
isInAnyRole in navbar.html in order to display a menu for users with roles 'ROLE_USER' and ROLE_SUPERVISOR'.

I have replace isInRole('ROLE_USER') by isInAnyRole(['ROLE_USER','ROLE_SUPERVISOR']).

But isInAnyRole is not called and none of the menus are displayed.

What is the good way to use isInAnyRole function?

Thanks

```html
<ul class="nav navbar-nav nav-pills">
                 <li ng-switch-when="true" class="dropdown-hover"  ng-class="{active: $state.includes('user')}" ng-show="isInAnyRole(['ROLE_USER','ROLE_SUPERVISOR'])">
```

and

```js
isInAnyRole: function (roles) {
    if (!_authenticated || !_identity.roles) {
        return false;
    }

    for (var i = 0; i < roles.length; i++) {
        if (_identity.roles.indexOf(roles[i]) !== -1) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: How do you know that `isInAnyRole()` is not called? Could you present some part of your code?

Comment: I am setting a breakpoint in isAnyRole() and a breakpoint in isInRole(). Execution steps in isInRole but not in isInAnyRole

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an old version of JHipster, since release 2.7.0 we provide a directive [authority.directive.js](https://github.com/jhipster/jhipster-sample-app/blob/master/src/main/webapp/scripts/components/auth/authority.directive.js) which does exactly what you want. You should consider upgrading your app.

Comment: I am about to deliver my app in production, is upgrading jhipster version safe?

Comment: It will very likely break your app because you are months behind. As an alternative just copy the directive and change your HTML templates to use it.

Comment: Could you, please, add an example of how to use it, or point us out a link to show it ?

Comment: Open a new question with your JHipster version and what you're looking for, it will avoid confusion with this old question